# Table With Scrollable Header - Using Transform/Translate

Tags: html, css

We worked out a neat trick to keep a fixed header on tables using:

```
$('#wrapper').on('scroll', function () {
    var translateY = 'translateY('+ this.scrollTop +'px)';

    $('thead th', this).css({
        '-webkit-transform': translateY,
        '-moz-transform': translateY,
        '-ms-transform': translateY,
        '-o-transform': translateY,
        'transform': translateY,
    });
});
```

You can see the working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/n9j0q7wq/

The only thing we cant figure out when you scroll the checkboxes appear OVER the header. Does anyone have a suggestion how this might be overcome?

Also. I'd rather find a way to make it happen without changing the position css property of those elements.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add z-index

```
.wrapper th {
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #50535a;
  border-left: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 85px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n9j0q7wq/2/

Comment: The only problem there is that the checkbox is no longer clickable.

Comment: Thats an idea, but the problem there is that the auto widths on the column contents will fail:

https://jsfiddle.net/n9j0q7wq/3/

Comment: That is not related with `z-index`, for auto width you will need to add `white-space: nowrap;`  on `td`. check fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/n9j0q7wq/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/n9j0q7wq/4/)